# Squid + Squidguard - redirect http traffic

Tags: linux, squid, iptables-redirect, squidguard

Im having trouble figuring out which is the best way to redirect the traffic for a certain subnet.

Basically i want to deny the access for a certain subnet to the internet. And i want it to always redirect the user to a specific (local) website.

We have a squid3 + squidguard proxy here that is managing the blocking of certain websites. I thought i could do it with it by using a whitelist and block everything else.

I tried to add this to the squidguard config

```
dest whitelist {
    domainlist      whitelist/domains
    urllist         whitelist/urls 
}


test{
                pass  whitelist none
                redirect http://bla.intern
}
```

and added the url http://bla.intern in the domains and urls file

Now i can visit http://bla.intern but when visiting other websites its not redireccting me just denying access.

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe over iptables?

Comment: little Update. It IS blocking urls but only direct Urls like google.com / reddit.com. As soon as there is anything behind it i can load it. like a google search or reddit.com/r/blah

I thought i could do it with expressions but somehow it doesnt work aswell.

Anyone an idea :)?